# DOMXPath - query

Tags: xpath, domxpath

XML File:

```
   <Domain Domaindetails="This tree display the domain we work">Root element
<Insurance>
    <InsuranceQ>
        <Devs>4</Devs>
        <QA>1</QA>
        <Total>5</Total>
    </InsuranceQ>
    <?billResource bill()?>
    <QuoteX/>
    <ProgressiveLeads>
       <Devs>3</Devs>
       <Total>6</Total>
       <QA>3</QA>
    </ProgressiveLeads>
</Insurance>
<BI>
    <MoboM/>
    <CloudFW>
        <Devs>4</Devs>
        <QA>4</QA>
        <Total>8</Total>
    </CloudFW>
    <?billResource bill()?>
</BI>
<Ecommerce>
    <USEcom/>
    <LXEcom/>
</Ecommerce>
<extrainfo>Co > S&S </extrainfo>
</Domain>
```

Traversing the projects under Insurance domain Hence wrote following code

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->load('project.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodeList=$xpath->query('//Domain/Insurance');

foreach($nodeList as $node)
{

    echo $node->nodeValue;  
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

It shows empty result. Am I having something wrong in my XML ?. The above code result in 415[devs,qa,total nodes] which is not the expected output.

I want to list 
InsuranceQ
QuoteX
Progressivelead as output.

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong...

Thanks,
Priti

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, formatted code (XML) would help understand problem faster. 
Ok. Coming back to your question, you can try `//Domain/Insurance/child::*` to get all the children of node `<Insurance>`.

Your XPath did not return expected results because you are not selecting children of node `<Insurance>`, you are just selecting `<Insurance>` node.

Hope this helps